# POP3 и вложения

Tags: pop3

Как вытаскивать вложения из писем? Надо приделать в самодельный pop3 клиент
или тут прям отдельный RFC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните с [Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045). Там много ссылок на сопутствующие RFC.

Если напишите парсер, то для его тестирования загляните:
[[Imap-protocol] IMAP4 section numbering algorithm](http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/imap-protocol/2007-November/000729.html).

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню спецификацию [POP3](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3) протокола - там нет ни слово о вложениях, протокол оперирует письмами, то есть получить письмо и удалить письмо. Следовательно вам нужен клиент который вытаскивает сообщение, выковыривает из них вложения и ... на счет удаления сообщения - как настроен клиент.

Comment: но ведь я получаю письмо целиком и всё, и в этой череде байтов и будет атачмент, тоесть приняв письмо, я сразу принимаю как текст, так и вложение, другое дело в том, как вычленить само вложение и правильно сохранить?

Comment: SMTP и POP - оперирует письмами, как неким набором строк последняя из которых содержит точку.  Вам нужен MIME парсер.

Comment: Да, если примитивно, то в unix- есть несколько command-line утилит, например fetchmail - забирает письмо с POP3, а uudeview - выковыривает вложения, и заставить их работать в паре не составит труда.